# Add label or failing check to Pull Request with (merge) conflict on GitHub?

Tags: github, merge, conflict, probot

If you work with GitHub project boards for PR management, it is quite important to be able to know about the status of a PR. Test failures are made available via the read `x` or green checkmark via checks, but (merge) conflicts are not visible in any way - you have to actually open the PR in a new tab.

Is there a way to add an automated `conflict` label ora failing check to a PR on GitHub if there is a (merge) conflict? (Both would be visible in a GitHub project board.)